# How to integrate a row in pascal's triangle?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I have a pascal's triangle with max rows of 5 . Lets suppose I want to find the integration of the fourth row . How do I access the fourth row in the pascal's triangle. `More precisely I want to know how to access a row in the pascal's triangle by entering the number n of the row`

> Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, pascal, columns;
    const int rows = 5;

    int **array = new int *[rows]; //generating array
    for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    array[i] = new int [columns];

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++){  //loop for te pascal's triangle
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            if(j == 0 || i == 0){
                pascal = 1;  //first element of pascal's triangle
            }
            else{
                pascal = pascal *(i - j + 1) / j; //pascal's triangle formula
            }
            cout << "  " << pascal; // printing pascals triangle
         }
         cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "enter which row to integrate: ";
    // here I want to directly access a row rather that entering the elements of the row 
    cin >> a1;
    cin >> a2;
    cin >> a3;
    cin >> a4;
    cin >> a5;

 }
```

1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1   ------> like of `n = 4` i want to integrate the elements of this row
1 4 6 4 1

> And the answer should be `for 1,3,3,1 = 0, 1, 1.5, 1, 0.25`

Comment: `columns` is not initialized, it's value may be anything. And `for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)` is out-of-bounds access. `array[rows-1]` is the biggest accessible element.

Comment: Does it change anything ?

Comment: Yes. How many colums are there in your array? Is 0 or -10 columns fine? Value of `columns` when you use it as array length can be *anything*. And accessing array out of bounds in best case will read next pieces of data (e.g. `array[3][5]` could read the value at `array[4][0]`). In worst case, you'll have [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: The program has Undefined Behaviour due to the bugs @Yksisarvinen points out. First order of business should be to get rid of any UB. As long as the program has UB it is impossible to reason about its behaviour since it has no defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first fill the array with the elements then you can access them like so (EDIT: Make sure to initialize the columns variable, I set it to 5)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int row_nb, pascal, columns = 5; //Initialized columns with columns = 5 
    const int rows = 5;

    int **array = new int *[rows]; //generating array
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
        array[i] = new int[columns];

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {  //loop for te pascal's triangle
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || i == 0) {
                pascal = 1;  //first element of pascal's triangle
            }
            else {
                pascal = pascal *(i - j + 1) / j; //pascal's triangle formula
            }
            array[i][j] = pascal; //fill the array
            cout << "  " << pascal; // printing pascals triangle
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "enter which row to intergrate: ";
    // here I want to directly access a row rather that entering the elements of the row 
    cin >> row_nb; //input the row you want to access

    for (int i = 0; i <= row_nb; i++) { //access the elements in this row in the array
    cout << array[row_nb][i] << " ";
}
    return 0; // add the return statement since the return type of the main function is int
}
```

Comment: If this helped you, kindly consider marking it as accepted answer; if not, please tell me more about your problem maybe I can help more :)

Comment: the count for `row_nb` should start from 0, so that by entering  `row_nb = 3` , I get `1,3,3,1` but I get  only `1,3,3` @Mahmoud Dafer

Comment: @ Mahmoud Dafer Can you help me with one more problem ?

Answer (score -1):

As I said [when you last asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53133454/accessing-a-row-in-pascals-triangle) :

You *could* simply store each row into a `std::vector<int>` as you calculate it (in addition to, or instead of, printing it), then keep a list of rows in a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Then, to access the nth row after calculating the triangle, you just grab the `n`th element of the second vector.

Comment: That's not how this works. You have all the needed information. *You* edit *your* code.